# Martingale optional stopping before a stopping time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, martingales

Here’s an easy one, I hope:

Suppose $\tau$ is a stopping time and $(M_t)$ is a martingale which together satisfy the hypotheses of the optional stopping theorem so that $\mathbb{E}[M_\tau]= \mathbb{E}[M_0]$.

Will it also be the case that $\mathbb{E}[M_\sigma]= \mathbb{E}[M_0]$ for an arbitrary random time $\sigma \leq \tau$, for example $\sigma= \tau-1$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The problem is that $\tau-1$ is not a "stopping time" for the martingale.

Example.  Martingale $(X_n), n=0,1,2$ is the standard random walk on $\mathbb Z$.  Our sample space is $[0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure.
\begin{align}
X_0(\omega) &= 0,\qquad \omega \in [0,1).
\\
X_1(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
1,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/2),
\\
-1,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,1).
\end{cases}
\\
X_2(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
2,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/4),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [1/4,1/2),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,3/4),\\
-2,\quad & \omega \in [3/4,1).
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The filtration $\mathcal F_0, \mathcal F_1, \mathcal F_2$ for this martingale:
$\mathcal F_0$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X_0$, so it is the trivial sigma-algebra with atom $[0,1)$.
$\mathcal F_1$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X_0, X_1$, so it is the sigma-algebra with atoms $[0,1/2), [1/2,1)$.
$\mathcal F_2$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X_0, X_1, X_2$, so it is the sigma-algebra with atoms $[0,1/4),[1/4,1/2),[1/2,3/4),[3/4,1)$.

Define stopping time $\tau = 2 \wedge \min\{n : X_n < 0\}.$  Then
\begin{align}
\tau(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
2,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/4),\\
2,\quad & \omega \in [1/4,1/2),\\
1,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,3/4),\\
1,\quad & \omega \in [3/4,1).
\end{cases}
\\
\sigma(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
1,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/4),\\
1,\quad & \omega \in [1/4,1/2),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,3/4),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [3/4,1).
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now $\tau$ is a stopping time, so of course $\mathbb E[X_\tau] = 0$.  But compute $\mathbb E[X_\sigma] = 1/2 \ne 0$, which shows that $\sigma$ is not a stopping time.  Computations:
\begin{align}X_\tau(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
2,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/4),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [1/4,1/2),\\
-1,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,3/4),\\
-1,\quad & \omega \in [3/4,1).
\end{cases}
\\
X_\sigma(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
1,\quad & \omega \in [0,1/4),\\
1,\quad & \omega \in [1/4,1/2),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [1/2,3/4),\\
0,\quad & \omega \in [3/4,1).
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Calculation that shows $\sigma$ is not a stopping time:
$$
\{\sigma = 0\} = [1/2,1) \notin \mathcal F_0.
$$

Comment: For future reference:  An "easy one" like this should be posted at https://math.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: My mistake on SE vs here. Thank you for putting that nicely, and for the clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even if $\sigma$ *is* a stopping time with $\sigma\le\tau$ the answer is No.

**Example:** Take your martingale to be a standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion $M$ with $M_0=0$, and then define $\sigma:=\inf\{t: M_t=1\}$ and $\tau:=\inf\{t>\sigma: M_t=0\}$. These are both finite (a.s.) stopping times. And clearly $0<\sigma<\tau$ and $M_\sigma=1$ but $M_\tau=0$ (a.s.), so $\Bbb E[M_\tau]=0=\Bbb E[M_0]$ but $\Bbb E[M_\sigma]=1\not=\Bbb E[M_0]$.

Comment: This is not quite an example because $M$ and $\tau$ don't satisfy the hypotheses of the optional stopping theorem, even though they do happen to satisfy its conclusion.

Comment: Granted. What are the optimal hypotheses for Optional Stopping?

Comment: The weakest hypothesis I know is to have $\{ M_{t \wedge \tau} : t \ge 0\}$ uniformly integrable.

Comment: I guess the original question is not quite well posed, as "the hypotheses of the optional stopping theorem" is ambiguous.